# How to delete range that contain content controls in word using JS Api

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, word-addins, javascript-api-for-office

i need to remove range from current doc that contains some contentControls with properties cannotEdit/cannotDelete = true. When i am trying to delete the range using range.delete(), word throwing error on console. Please advice how a can delete a range with all cc. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since cannotDelete = true, it means this content control cannot be deleted. So it is expected that range.delete() throws exception. if you do want to delete it, you can first change the cannotDelete to false of the content controls inside the range.